# mongoexport Failed: (CursorNotFound) Cursor not found

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

My mongo cluster use version 4.0, I'm trying to use mongoexport to export the collection with json, when I'm running `mongoexport -h 192.168.1.100 --port 8635 u exporter -p 'xxxxxxx' --readPreference nearest -d activity_account -c account_detail -o activity.json`, However, after a few minutes,the process exits and I get an error saying `CursorNotFound`:

```
2021-04-23T17:52:41.534+0800    [#######.................]  activity_account.account_detail  81880000/246907744  (33.2%)
2021-04-23T17:52:42.534+0800    [#######.................]  activity_account.account_detail  81928000/246907744  (33.2%)
2021-04-23T17:52:43.534+0800    [#######.................]  activity_account.account_detail  81976000/246907744  (33.2%)
2021-04-23T17:52:44.534+0800    [#######.................]  activity_account.account_detail  82024000/246907744  (33.2%)
2021-04-23T17:52:45.534+0800    [#######.................]  activity_account.account_detail  82072000/246907744  (33.2%)
2021-04-23T17:52:46.534+0800    [#######.................]  activity_account.account_detail  82120000/246907744  (33.3%)
2021-04-23T17:52:46.596+0800    [#######.................]  activity_account.account_detail  82129096/246907744  (33.3%)
2021-04-23T17:52:46.596+0800    Failed: (CursorNotFound) Cursor not found (namespace: 'activity_account.account_detail', id: 8485951729809496567).
```

What's happend and how can I fix it? Or maybe is it has another way to export to json?

Comment: Did you try default readPreference?

Comment: How many are "few" minutes? Is the server configured to have a non-standard cursor timeout?

Comment: I'm trying to use different readPreference like secondaryPreferred、nearest and primary, but it's also faild, Some times it runs for one hours, some times it only can be run for half hour

Answer (score 0):

After I changed the mongoexport client to r4.0.24, the problem did not appear again.Before this I had mongo Server 4.0 and mongoexport 4.2